# B-splines basis function

Tags: interpolation, spline

If the image domain is denoted as $\Omega_I=\{(x,y,z)| 0 \leq x<X,0\leq y<Y, 0 \leq z <Z \}$. Let $\Phi$ denote a $n_x \times n_y \times n_z$ mesh of control points points $\phi_{i,j,k}$ with uniform spacing. The 3D tensor product of cubic B-splines can be written like this:

\begin{equation}
T(x,y,z)= \sum^3_{l=0}\sum^3_{m=0}\sum^3_{n=0}B_l(u)B_m(v)B_n(w)\phi_{i+l,j+m,k+n}
\end{equation}
where $i=\lfloor \frac{x}{n_x}\rfloor-1, j=\lfloor \frac{y}{n_y}\rfloor-1, k=\lfloor \frac{z}{n_z}\rfloor-1, u = \frac{x}{n_x}-\lfloor \frac{x}{n_x}\rfloor,v = \frac{y}{n_y}-\lfloor \frac{y}{n_y}\rfloor, w= \frac{z}{n_z}-\lfloor \frac{z}{n_z}\rfloor$. $B_l$ are the $l$-th basis functions:

\begin{equation}
B_0(u) = (1-u)^3/6
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B_1(u) = (3u^3-6u^2+4)/6
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B_2(u) = (-3u^3+3u^2+3u+1)/6
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
B_3(u) = u^3/6
\end{equation}

If I want to use trilinear interpolation instead i.e. to formulate a tensor product using first degree splines. Is the following formulation correct?

\begin{equation}
T(x,y,z)= \sum^1_{l=0}\sum^1_{m=0}\sum^1_{n=0}B_l(u)B_m(v)B_n(w)\phi_{i+l,j+m,k+n}
\end{equation}

In such a case what are the basis functions equivalent to?

Answer (score 1):

your formulation in this case would contain the linear functions, but would be bigger: $uvw$ is not linear. basically you get sums of **products** of argument-wise linear splines.

you can overcome this by restricting the coefficients of the product-of-linear-functions-splines to be zero. (the practicabillity of this approach depends on the task. least squares fitting with these constraints for instance would be possible.)

EDIT: i found an image for another approach for linear interpolation (by a nodal base, often used for fem for instance) here is the image:
https://cdn.comsol.com/cyclopedia/finite-element-method/base-functions-overlap.en_US.png

Comment: I have corrected that, in 3D is trilinear interpolation. Is the above correct now?

Comment: if trilinear interpolation refers to tensor products of linear splines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ yes. just wanted to make sure you see the difference.

Comment: stop for one moment: in your base splines only monomes up to order 1 should appear for that case. (didn't notice that all the splines you gave have monomes of order 3 first) so your base splines are probably $u$ and $1-u$

Comment: @Gina please see my last comment, it's important.

Comment: So in 1D we from definition that the basis functions of linear interpolation are the so called hat functions. As shown in the image you had send me. There I've noticed an overlap in 2D case. How can we avoid this?

Comment: the overlap exists also in 1d ($u$ und $1-u$ overlap in the same way) and thus cannot be avoided entirely. note that they do **not overlap in the nodes**. edit: give me a moment, i will try to explain later, am buisy right now

Comment: I have noticed that the basis functions I provides in the beginning are of order 3 because those are the basis functions for cubic B-splines. If the basis for trilinear interpolation are going to be u and 1-u. Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: as the basis for linear one dimensional spline interpolition you can take $B_0(u):=1-u$ and $B_1(u):=u$. then you can take the tensor-product to get splines in 3 dimensions. this basis generates a space that contains, but is actually bigger than the linear functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$ since it also contains products of component-wise linear functions (for instance $B_1(u)\cdot B_1(v)\cdot B_1(w)=u\cdot v\cdot w$) you can overcome this with linear constraints on the coefficients such that only summands of the form $B_i(u)\cdot(B_0(v)+B_1(v))\cdot(B_0(w)+B_1(w))$, (TO BE CONTINUED)

Comment: $(B_0(u)+B_1(u))\cdot B_i(v)\cdot(B_0(w)+B_1(w))$, $(B_0(u)+B_1(u))\cdot(B_0(v)+B_1(v))\cdot B_i(w)$ and $(B_0(u)+B_1(u))\cdot(B_0(v)+B_1(v))\cdot (B_0(w)+B_1(w))$ occur, which span a base for the linear functions (EDIT: note that $B_0(u)+B_1(u)=1$). But since this is much effort, I would recommend you in this case, NOT to use products of linear splines, but instead a piecewiese linear nodal base instead.